# Setting up Zencart with Paypal

Tags: paypal, zen-cart

1. To begin: I am trying to setup Zencart with Paypal. I have followed all of Paypal and Zencart's instructions:

Putting in Paypal's API username, password and signature code into Zencart's Payment Module section. Checked the "live" environment.

I then tried buying a product on the website and got the following error message:

Zen Cart message: We are sorry for the inconvenience. The PayPal account
authentication settings are not yet set up, or the API security information
is incorrect.

10002
Security error
Security header is not valid

I have tried looking up the answer but everything I see says to make sure the environment is not in sandbox and that everything is typed in correctly. I have tripled checked and the API is typed in correctly and it is set to live.... what else can I do?

1. Moving on, I have tried to setup the sandbox but am unfamiliar with how to use Paypal's sandbox. So I reconfigured Zencart to "sandbox mode" with the appropriate sandbox API and I set up box a sandbox account for a merchant and private buyer but I don't know how to use them. Should I go back to the Zencart store and register with my new "Paypal sandbox private buyer email"? And will checking out using this email they gave me work as just a test... I don't want to go through with the checkout if I'm going to get billed...

Thank you for any help:)

Answer (score 0):

The best place to get support on Zen Cart issues is directly on the Zen Cart support forum at http://www.zen-cart.com/forum.php

Further, an existing article already explains the basics of the problem you describe: http://www.zen-cart.com/content.php?277-the-paypal-account-in-this-store-is-presently-misconfigured-to-use-mixed-sandbox-and-live-settings-we-are-unable-to-complete-your-transaction-please-notify-the-store-owner-so-they-can-correct-this-problem-10002

It is absolutely critical that the THREE parts of your API settings (username, password, signature) be copied EXACTLY from PayPal's site into your store's admin settings screen.

There's no need to use sandbox unless you're a programmer writing new features for payment processing. So be sure to check the "Live" radio-button. (I realize you already mentioned that. Just adding this for clarity.)

You can also get more details on exactly what is coming back from PayPal by turning on debug logging in the module's settings.

PayPal tech support is available at www.paypal.com/mts - they can look at your actual transmissions and at your account, and sort out a problem if there's something wrong with the API signature details.